# Yes/No buttons in Inno Setup not translating

Tags: translation, inno-setup

I am using unicode Inno Setup (5.4.2u), and **none** of the *Yes*/*No* buttons in the dialog boxes are translating. Has anyone found a way around this?

Thank you
Dave

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the docs, this is not a problem with InnoSetup but is a function of Windows itself:
http://www.jrsoftware.org/iskb.php?translatebuttons

From the page: The button captions are in the same language as Windows itself. So if the user is running an English edition of Windows, they will see English button captions.

Comment: And there's no way to translate them?

Comment: This is a Windows behavior, I would think you'd want to keep the behavior standard. There is no way to translate them that I've tried or considered.  This link (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32097845/inno-setup-use-own-button-texts-on-messagebox) has a link to a callback but I've never used it so I'm not sure if it'll work.