# Inno-Setup: use own button texts on messagebox

Tags: inno-setup

It is common practice in good GUI design to not use Yes-No-messageboxes but give the buttons real names, e.g. Save or Discard. How we can achieve this in messageboxes displayed with `MsgBox` in InnoSetup, at least for the ones we show in the code section?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`MsgBox`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_msgbox) function uses internally the [`MessageBox`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645505(v=vs.85).aspx) Windows API function which allows you to use only a specific set of predefined buttons or button groups. What's worse, the buttons cannot be easily localized (without a hook [like this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18399/Localizing-System-MessageBox)). So, to have custom button texts you would need to use such hook and change the texts before showing your dialog, show the dialog and after that change them back to the common texts (because Inno Setup uses this dialog too).

Another, easier option would be making custom form.